# Changing value on click HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to increment a per product quantity value in my table by clicking a button. I got an Add `button` at the end of each product in my table so If I want to increment the first quantity value of the first product, I'm just gonna click the first button at the first line. If I want to increment the second product's quantity, I will simply click the button at the second line and so on..

Here is the `table` in my HTML file(Ignore the remove `button`):

```
    <tbody>
      {%for stock in stocks%}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{stock.stockId}}</th>
        <td>{{stock.name}}</td>
        <td>{{store.name}}</td>
        <td class="mystore-quantity">{{stock.quantity}}</td>
        <td>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-action="add"
            data-product="{{stock.id}}"
            class="btn btn-primary ml-2 mb-1 action-btn"
          >
            Add
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-product="{{stock.id}}"
            class="btn btn-danger ml-2 mb-1 action-btn"
            data-action="remove"
          >
            Sell
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and this is the JS file (Ignore the `updateStock` call):

```
const actionBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('action-btn');
const quantity = document.getElementsByClassName('mystore-quantity');
console.log(quantity[0])
for (let i = 0; i < actionBtns.length; i++)
{
    actionBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      
        const productId = this.dataset.product;
        const action = this.dataset.action;
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action )
        if(user == 'AnonymousUser'){
            console.log('User not logged in')
        } else {
            console.log(quantity.textContent)


            updateStock(productId,action)
 
        }
    })


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` key word to target the clicked button and use `closest()` to target the parent *tr*. From that *tr* element you can get the respective *td* element using `querySelector()`.

**Demo:**

```js
const actionBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('action-btn');
//const quantity = document.getElementsByClassName('mystore-quantity');
//console.log(quantity[0])
for (let i = 0; i < actionBtns.length; i++){
  actionBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    const el = this.closest('tr').querySelector('.mystore-quantity');
    el.textContent = Number(el.textContent) + 1;
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">11</th>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td class="mystore-quantity">1</td>
        <td>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-action="add"
            data-product="{{stock.id}}"
            class="btn btn-primary ml-2 mb-1 action-btn"
          >
            Add
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-product="{{stock.id}}"
            class="btn btn-danger ml-2 mb-1 action-btn"
            data-action="remove"
          >
            Sell
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">22</th>
        <td>mnl</td>
        <td>asd</td>
        <td class="mystore-quantity">2</td>
        <td>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-action="add"
            data-product="{{stock.id}}"
            class="btn btn-primary ml-2 mb-1 action-btn"
          >
            Add
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-product="{{stock.id}}"
            class="btn btn-danger ml-2 mb-1 action-btn"
            data-action="remove"
          >
            Sell
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: @AliZiyaÇEVİK, you are most welcome, glad to help:)